# Custom routes for server handlers in NuxtJS

Tags: nuxt.js

Currently, I have set some server handlers in my server/api directory.
However, due to some architecture constraints, the backend will take the same `/api` path.

To mitigate this, I found out that I can have a `server/route` directory, which will give me the same server handler but the path being something like `/myapi` for `server/route/myapi.ts`.

Curious, if this is a proper way of doing `custom` server handler paths (or even if it's okay to do, i'm fine with that too) or if there are others ways.

Thank you

Edit:

This is the proper way to do things per docs:

https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/server#server-routes